# Simple Program in Drracket Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to design a program in DrRacket which takes in two variables (a and b) and returns b.
How would this be done?

Comment: How does a function that takes two arguments begin?

Comment: You mean the program should take command line arguments and return a error code to the operating system or are you asking how to make a function?

Comment: @Sylwester I'm asking how to make this function, this is my first time using DrRacket.

Comment: Have [a look at this](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_prologue.html).

Comment: D.P. can you express what you want in algebra notation, like `f(x,y) = 5x + 2y`?

Comment: @AlexKnauth f(x,y) = y

Comment: Looks like you need to read a little bit about the basics of Racket syntax. DrRacket comes with an excellent set of documentation - select "Racket Documentation" in the Help menu, and follow one of the "Quick : An Introduction ..." or "How to Design Programs" links.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the beginner language in DrRacket. In DrRacket you can associate value to variables using `define`. e.x `(define A 10)`. If we wanted to make this a function in racket, we could do  `(define (always10 n) A)` where as we make a function that takes in n which is useless in this case, as it does nothing, and returns a previously defined term called A. With your question it is the same, except it takes in one extra variable and it returns the second parameter. it would be written as `(define (someFunction a b) b)`. If we called `someFunction` we would have to provide it 2 arguements of any type and it would return the second one. `(someFunction "hello" A) => 10`. Next I encourage you to make a function that takes in 2 numbers and return their sum.